# Image of connected set

Tags: general-topology

If $A=\left\{(x,y)|x^2+(y-3)^2\le4\right\}\cap\left\{(x,y)|x^2+y^2\le2\right\}$ prove that $f(A)$ is connected and compact set if $f(x,y)=e^{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$. It is easy to prove that A is path connected and as that connected. For $f(A)=\left\{(x,y)|f(x,y)\in A\right\}$ i know that image of connected set is also connected, but how to use that here?

Answer (score 2):

So, you already know that $f(A)$ is connected. On the other hand, $A$ is compact (since it is closed and bounded), and so (since $f$ is continuous) $f(A)$ is compact too.